# Good event calendaring / scheduling design guide?

Tags: calendar, scheduling

In an application I'm designing, the user has to be able to specify rather complex event scheduling (continuous time-block vs. daily time-blocks, exception date/times, recurrence patterns etc.)

Does anyone know of a good design page for such a thing online?  For example, I was highly impressed with [this page's](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506085627/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041807-1.shtml) description of how to do database audit trails, and would love something similar.

### Current thinking

1. My database would contain of the following tables: Events and ScheduleItems

   - The relationship would be Events {1 -- 0..*} ScheduleItems
   - Events would have the following columns: eventId, schedulePattern
   - ScheduleItems would have the following columns: eventId, startDateTime, endDateTime
2. The front end controls would allow the user to specify general rules (daily/continuous, includes/excludes weekends, start/end date/time etc.).  If they are not satisfied with the existing controls, they could then opt to display and manually tweak the generated "time-blocks"
3. On saving the event schedule...

   - If only the provided controls were used (no tweaking) I would save their selections as a pattern in the Events table (i.e. "sd:2010-04-28;st:09:20:00;ed:2010-05-12;et:17:20:00;r:2w[M-Th];z:EST" etc.)
   - If the user manually tweaked the generated time-blocks, I would save each individual time-block within the the ScheduleItems table and have Events.schedulePattern be given a special code ("MANUAL" or something).

#### Pros

I should be able to save > 90% of the events through the pattern field directly, and be able to handle any other corner cases through the "brute-force" ScheduleItems table.  Since some of the handled cases include events that can go on for months (which would otherwise result in a very large number of time-blocks), having it in one line is rather attractive.

#### Cons

This is a fairly complex solution; any other system requiring this data would need to be able to handle parsing the schedulePattern *as well* as knowing when to fetch ScheduleItems.

Comment: Did you come up with a table design that works? Can you share it?

Answer (score 1):

The "schedulePattern", in a mature way, uses [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) format to store the users' schedule is a good idea for running task.

This format is simple but sophisticated. In relational database, there would be some performance benefit if you seperate every "entry" of Cron to a column of table with suitable indexes.

The effort, however, is the translation between this format and user interface. And the raw data to which user input should be recorded originally.

I would design two kinds of table, one for raw data inputted by user, another for running task for schedule.